# Updated Applescript to hide folders on Desktop for El Capitan

Tags: applescript

I would like to hide all folders on Desktop. I found the following AppleScript but somehow it doesn't work under el Capitan (I'm running 10.11.5 version) :

```
try
set toggle to do shell script "defaults read com.apple.finder CreateDesktop"
if toggle = "true" then
do shell script "defaults write com.apple.finder CreateDesktop false"
else if toggle = "false" then
do shell script "defaults write com.apple.finder CreateDesktop true"
end if
end try
do shell script "killall Finder"
delay 0.5
activate application "Finder"
```

Thanks in advance for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your *found* AppleScript has some issues.

The value of the key `CreateDesktop` – like the more popular `AppleShowAllFiles` – is a boolean.

Boolean values of user defaults return "1" or "0" (string) in a `do shell script` call for a couple of system versions. It's never "true" or "false". To get an usable result you need to coerce it to `integer` and then to `boolean`

```
((do shell script "/usr/bin/defaults read com.apple.finder CreateDesktop") as integer) as boolean
```

If the key does not exist (the default value is false) catch the thrown error, then toggle the boolean state and write is back with `-bool` attribute to ensure not to write a string.

After sending `killall` the Finder relaunches automatically, there's no need to do that in code.

This script can be used also for the `AppleShowAllFiles` key to show and hide invisible files.

```
try
    set state to ((do shell script "/usr/bin/defaults read com.apple.finder CreateDesktop") as integer) as boolean
on error
    set state to false
end try
do shell script "/usr/bin/defaults write com.apple.finder CreateDesktop -bool " & ((not state) as text) & "; killall Finder"
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked like a charm. I did not have time to dig into applescript for now.